# ReactRouter Link dynamic param not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've create a route

```
<ReactRouter.Route path="/brand/:brandId" handler={BrandManage}/>
```

And I can hit the route with

```
/brand/idnumber
```

But I want to generate dynamic links.  According to the [docs](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#Link) I should be able to do something like:

```
<ReactRouter.Link to="/brand" params={{ brandId: this.props.data.get('_id') }}>
      Edit
</ReactRouter.Link>
```

But the link generated goes to

```
/brand
```

Should I just update my route to use

```
/brand
```

?

Comment: Did you try adding a name prop to your Route? something like <ReactRouter.Route name="brand" path="/brand/:brandId" handler={BrandManage}/>

Answer (score 0):

`<ReactRouter.Link to={this.props.data.url + this.props.data.get('_id')}>
          Edit
 </ReactRouter.Link>`

instead of

```
<ReactRouter.Link to="/brand" params={{ brandId: this.props.data.get('_id') }}>
         Edit
</ReactRouter.Link>
```

Achieved what I was looking for